# Understanding $O(2^n)$ time complexity due to recursive functions

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

Consider the following binary recursive fibonassi program:

```
Algorithm binaryFib(k)  //k is assumed to be non-negative integer
   if (k <= 1)
      return k
   else
      return binaryFib(k-1) + binaryFib(k-2)
end binaryFib
```

The recurrence relation for above is:

$T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)$

The run time complexity for the same is $O(2^n)$, as can be seen in below pic for $n=8$:

[image]

However if you look at the bottom of the tree, say by taking $n=3$, it wont run $2^n$ times at each level:

[image]

**Q1.** Wont this fact have any effect on time complexity or does the time complexity $O(2^n)$ ignores this fact?

**Q2.** I guess I can rephrase Q1 by eliminating above fact with following recurrence relation: $T(n) = 2 T(n-1)$. Does this recurrence relation still have same $O(2^n)$ time complexity?

**Q3.** Finally I want to generalize: Does the recurrence relation $T(n)=k\times T(n-1)$ have $O(k^n)$ time complexity?

Comment: Big O-notation gives a certain _upper bound_ on the complexity of the function, and as you have correctly guessed, `fib` is in fact not using 2^n time.  The complexity of the recursive `fib` is actually `fib` itself?!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code, it is quite obvious that there are exactly fib(N) - 1 additions. Therefore the time complexity is $\Theta(fib(n))$.